# Check existing data and Loop Back

Tags: php, pdo

Hello so I have a code that will generate a random number and echo out "UNIQUE" if its not in the database. Here is my code:

```
$require 'connection.php';
try {
    $generateID = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $checkRandomString = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE generatedID = ?");
    $checkRandomString->execute(array($generateID));
    $row = $checkRandomString->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row > 0) {
        // loop back and generate again until it echos out "UNIQUE"
    } else {
        echo "UNIQUE";
    }
} catch {PDOException $e} {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What I wanted to do is if the `$generatedID` is existing, I want it to automatically generate again until it echo's out `"UNIQUE"`. How can I do that?

Comment: put your code in a function, and then you can self call the function in your `if($row > 0) { ...}` block

Comment: @Sean will try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a do while to do what you've described.

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS num_found 
FROM myTable 
WHERE generatedID = ?"
$checkRandomString = $conn->prepare($query);

do{
   $generateID = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
   $checkRandomString->execute(array($generateID));
   $row = $checkRandomString->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}while($row['num_found'] > 0);
```

Is there a reason it has to be "random" though? you could just use an autoincrement id.

Comment: Hi, where did you get num_found? Thank you

Comment: num_found is the 'column' she assigned the result to.  Looks great to me, I agree with @Jessica and am confused as to why it must be random.  Take a look at `$STMT->rowCount()` as well.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment I am using this PHP PDO Class http://pastebin.com/VLh2cFbv and I'm trying to convert Jessica's answer with that class. Will this code work? http://i.imgur.com/esFrj8k.png

Comment: @FewFlyBy I do not know and I really don't feel like reading that whole class, I recommend asking a new question.